# How to set project_id and domain in create stack

Tags: openstack

I have created an stack via [this](https://docs.openstack.org/api-ref/orchestration/v1/?expanded=create-stack-detail#create-stack) api. It is created successfully. The problem is that although I send a `project_id` as a `tenant_id`, it creates a new project with different `project_id`. The name of this project starts with the `tenant_id`. I would like it to use the `tenant_id` as its `project_id`. I also want to set its domain but I could not find any related parameter. The server name also has random postfix.

I have sent a `POST` request to `:8004/v1/5ac.../stacks`. In header, I have `X-Auth-Token` and `Content-type: application-json`. I have also specified the `project_id` when the token is generated. The response is `201`.

**Input:**

```
{
    "stack_name": "software-test-26",
    "parameters": {
        "NetID": "0269..."
    },
    "template": {
        "heat_template_version": "2015-10-15",
        "description": "some description",
        "parameters": {
            "NetID": {
                "type": "string",
                "description": "some description"
            }
        },
        "resources": {
            "server": {
                "type": "OS::Nova::Server",
                "properties": {
                    "image": "Cirros",
                    "flavor": "Min",
                    "key_name": "key_name",
                    "networks": {
                        "0" : {
                            "network": {
                                "get_param": "NetID"
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        },
        "outputs": {
            "instance_name": {
                "description": "Name of the instance.",
                "value": {
                    "get_attr": { 
                        "0" : "server",
                        "1" : "name"
                        }
                }
            },
            "instance_ip": {
                "description": "IP address of the instance.",
                "value": 
                    {
                        "get_attr": {
                        "0" : "server",
                        "1" : "first_address"
                        }
                    }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The output is something like in openstack document.

Comment: I don't see any project or tenant ID in the input. How do you submit it? How can Heat create a project if no project is mentioned in the template?

Comment: @berndbausch I send it in the path `5ac...` in the `:8004/v1/5ac.../stacks` is the `tenant_id`. It creates another project with different project_id. I want it not to create a new project and use the old one.

Comment: Why can't you use the old one? Does it disappear? And how do you know that a new project is created? This is really strange; in my opinion, the only way a "stack create" API can create a new project is through directives in the template.

Comment: @berndbausch I want to use the admin project in default domain. I send its `project_id` as a `tenant_id` in the url. I also use this `project_id` to generate `X-Auth-Token`. After creating stack, I have a new project in the list of projects. The id of this project is different from `tenant_id` but its name has a prefix of `tentant_id`.